# Docker Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:69840575665060 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker

I have two container. The first container has unicorn and the second container has the mongod.

```
        Name                     Command             State            Ports           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_mongodb_1     /entrypoint.sh mongod         Up      0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp 
app_web_1         foreman start                 Up      0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp
```

When i try access my rails application returns the error `not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:69840575665060 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>`, but when i enter with `docker-compose web run rails c` i can save document: `f = Feature.new(name: "test", value: 10) => #<Feature _id: 565deac0616e642856000000, name: "test", value: 10, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> => f.save => true`

**config/mongodb.yml**

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app_development
      hosts:
        - mongodb
      options:
  options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app_test
      hosts:
        - mongodb
      options:
        read: primary
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app_production
      hosts:
        - mongodb
      options:
        read: primary
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

I do not understand, it is that the bug is on `127.0.0.1`, but in the configuration file i haven't defined this address.

**/etc/hosts**

```
172.17.0.3  mongodb 49ea2c077967 app_mongodb
```

Comment: Did you ever find  solution to this?

Comment: No, I could not fix this problem.